# Problema ao editar informações de cadastro que tem verificação de unicidade

Tags: java, aplicação-web, play-framework

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web utilizando o play Framework. No próprio play tem a anotação @Unique que me garante que dados iguais não podem ser salvos no banco. Adicionei essa anotação para os campos de nome de usuário e e-mail do meu formulário, funciona corretamente, o problema é que ao clicar em editar o meu funcionário e não alterar esses dados a anotação impede de fazer o procedimento. Exemplo, vou alterar somente o nome do funcionário, sem mexer nos outros campos, a anotação verifica que e-mail e nome de usuário já esta cadastrado e não deixa salvar a alteração. Portanto, alguém pode me ajudar a resolver este problema?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou utilizando o mesmo formulário de cadastro para realizar a ediçao do forms.

```
 <div class="row">
 <form action="@{funcionarios.salvarFuncionarios}" method="post">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="hidden" name="funcionario.id" value="${f?.id}" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nome completo:</label> <input type="text"
                name="funcionario.nome" class="form-control"
                value="${flash['funcionario.nome'] ? flash['funcionario.nome'] : f?.nome}">
            <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.nome' /}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email:</label> <input type="text" name="funcionario.email"
                class="form-control"
                value="${flash['funcionario.email'] ? flash['funcionario.email'] : f?.email}">
            <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.email' /}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Função:</label> <select name="funcionario.funcao"
                class="form-control"
                value="${flash['funcionario.funcao'] ? flash['funcionario.funcao'] : f?.funcao}">
                <option>Administrador</option>
                <option>Suporte</option>
                <option>Supervisor</option>
            </select> <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.funcao' /}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nível de acesso:</label> <select
                name="funcionario.nivelAcesso" class="form-control"
                value="${flash['funcionario.nivelAcesso'] ? flash['funcionario.nivelAcesso'] : f?.nivelAcesso}">
                <option>Administrador</option>
                <option>Suporte</option>
            </select> <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.nivelAcesso'
                /}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nome de usuário:</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Mínimo 5 caracteres"
                name="funcionario.login" class="form-control"
                value="${flash['funcionario.login'] ? flash['funcionario.login'] : f?.login}">
            <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.login' /}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Senha:</label> <input type="password" placeholder="Mínimo 6 caracteres"
                name="funcionario.senha" class="form-control"
                value="${flash['funcionario.senha'] ? flash['funcionario.senha'] : f?.senha}">
            <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.senha' /}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Confirmar senha:</label> <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Mínimo 6 caracteres"
                class="form-control"> <span class="alert-danger">#{error
                'senha' /}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger"
            onclick="window.location.href='/funcionarios/listagemFuncionarios';">
            Cancelar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Meu controller funcionarios:

```
public static void salvarFuncionarios(@Valid Funcionario funcionario, String senha) throws Exception {

    if (validation.hasErrors() || !funcionario.senha.equals(senha)) {
        params.flash();
        validation.keep();
        formFuncionarios();
    }
    funcionario.senha = Crypto.passwordHash(senha);
    String mensagem = "Cadastro realizado com sucesso!";
    flash.success(mensagem);
    funcionario.save();
    listagemFuncionarios(null);
}

public static void editarFuncionarios(Long id) {
    Funcionario f = Funcionario.findById(id);
    renderTemplate("Funcionarios/formFuncionarios.html", f);
}
```

Comment: Quando vc tenta **editar** um registro, alterando seu email e usuário, um novo registro é criado no banco ?

Comment: sim, isso mesmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
`Agente funcionarioBanco = Agente.find("email = ? or login = ?", funcionario.email, funcionario.login).first();

    if (funcionario.id == null) {
        if (funcionarioBanco != null && funcionarioBanco.id != funcionarioBanco.id && funcionarioBanco.foto == null) {
            validation.addError("funcionario.email", "E-mail já existente");
            validation.addError("funcionario.login", "Usuário já existente");
            validation.addError("funcionario.foto", "Imagem já cadastrada");
        }`
```